# Multiple camera modules for analyzing objects up close

Tags: pi-3, camera

I want to build a system where there are 3 cameras connected to the Pi (v3), for up close image processing, the quality isn't necessary, as long it can detect small objects (~0.5cm wide to ~8cm long)

I will be building a board and positioning the 3 cameras every 120° will triangulate objects in the middle of the board, perhaps about 30cm from afar, by using OpenCV to detect those items by loading all the cameras with picamera for example, not requiring high fps, 10fps or less will be just fine.

Is it possible to create a mesh of 3 camera modules connected to 1 Pi? Using a multi-plexer of some kind to connect the 15-pin cables into 1? Not sure what the required hardware will be needed here to connect them?

Comment: Welcome @Jacob! You seem to be on the right track; if you search online for "Raspberry Pi camera multiplexer" you'll find some of these devices for sale. Some are quite expensive, so you could also consider using three individual Raspberry Pis, with a camera each. The advantage of that would be that you could get simultaneous samples from all three angles, whereas with a multiplexer you could only take an image from a certain angle at a time.

Comment: That might be more ideal. Perhaps 3 Pi Zeros, each with a camera module. Then they can distribute the images from each camera?

Comment: you could connect them all to the same network and have one of the Raspberry Pis receive the images from the other two, and do all the processing in one Pi. Or even better, figure out if your algorithm can be parallelized and distribute (some of) the processing load between the three.

Comment: I guess putting 3 Pis together with serial communication would be the best approach, but what kind of hardware would be required to put all 3 to communicate with each other? They are close to each other. I can visualise like you mentioned, the processing load could be worked across them.

Comment: I don't have any experiencing connecting multiple Raspberry Pis to each other unless it's through WiFi, but I'm guessing you want some other option. You should probably post a new question about that.